# How to join 2 tables when one might be empty

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have 2 very simple tables.  Let's call the first Table_A, which has columns Col_1 and Col_2, and let's call the second Table_B, which has columns Col_a and Col_b.  Col_1 and Col_a is the key between both tables.  So, let's say that I want to do a simple join, such as

```
  SELECT
    Table_A.Col_1,
    Table_A.Col_2,
    Table_B.Col_b
    FROM Table_A
    LEFT JOIN Table_B
    ON Table_A.Col_1 = Table_B.Col_a
    WHERE Table_A.Col_2 <> Table_B.Col_b
```

The problem I am encountering is that Table_B could be empty, which means that this query will not return any records.  In that situation, I want the query to just return all records in Table_A.  What is the best way to resolve this?

Here is some sample data:-

```
Table_A:-

Col_1 Col_2
-----------
x     1
y     3

Table_B:-

Col_a Col_b
-----------
x     1   
y     4
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The LEFT JOIN accomplishes exactly what you seem to want.

Comment: Why do you think the left join will not return any record from Table_A when Table_B is empty? Your query looks just fine.

Comment: In reality, for this join, I actually have an additional WHERE clause, in which I only want to return records such that Table_A.Col_2 <> Table_B.Col_b.  That query didn't return any records (which was a surprise).  So, I then checked Table_B, and saw that it was empty.

Comment: I commented out my WHERE clause, and I do get the desired behavior (i.e., all records from Table_A return).  So, the problem is in my WHERE clause, not in the fact that Table_B could be empty.  I want the WHERE condition to be applied per key.  So, say we have Col_1 = Col_a = 'x'.  For all records with a value of 'x', I only want the records to return in this query if Col_2 does not equal Col_b.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the where clause that is failing as well a brief sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret the question/comments correctly at this point you want a WHERE clause that will filter the results to records that have either NULL for Table_B.Col_b or a do not match to Table_A.Col_1. The equivalent of WHERE Table_A.Col_1 <> Table_B.Col_b OR Table_B.Col_b IS NULL.

```
 SELECT Col_1,
        Col_2,
        Col_b
   FROM Table_A
        LEFT JOIN 
        Table_B ON Col_1 = Col_a
  WHERE Col_1 <> ISNULL(Col_b,-Col_1) --I use -Col_1 since i don't know a literal values that will always be different.
```